# What is the translation of this ancient Greek verb πυθαγοριζει

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ho.history-overview, translation

Here it is used in a sentence

> It is therefore a priori probable that Plato πυθαγοριζει in the passage where he says that between two planes one mean suffices, but to connect two solids, two means are necessary.  - Sir Thomas Heath: A History of Greek Mathematics, Volume I: From Thales to Euclid, [page 89](https://books.google.com/books?id=bifEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA89)

I realize this is not an equation question, but this forum might seems an appropriate place to ask a question about words used in discussions of number theory

Comment: I guess it means something like 'to act or reason like a Pythagorician". In any case, it would be helpful to tell us from which Plato's book this verb comes.

Comment: I have added the text where it is most likely taken from. If needed, plese edit your post to correct this, user120785.

Comment: For the intertwining and influences between what appears to be today Plato's and Pythagora's heritage, the works of Jules Vuillemin are enlightening. You should for instance check "Mathématiques platoniciennes et pythagoriciennes" and the associated references.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I wanted to upvote your comment but, due to a clumsy manoeuvre, this has been cancelled (so that it stays to one). If somebody reads me, I would be glad this be corrected.

Comment: There is also a [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/), and it welcomes some questions about Greek. Plato and his works are at least on-topic. If you want to have this question migrated there and MO moderators don't object, it's possible.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42864817#42864817

Comment: For an old example, see [Eusebius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusebius)' apologetic work *Εὑαγγελικὴ προπαρασκευή*, commonly known by its Latin title [Praeparatio evangelica (Preparation for the Gospel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praeparatio_evangelica). The book is an attempt to prove the excellence of Christianity over pagan religions and philosophy and contains information from historians and philosophers not recorded elsewhere, including reference to Platonists. 1/2

Comment: See [Book XV, 37](https://books.google.it/books?id=Hzm4CIgwpbwC&pg=PA112), dicussing theories of *Physici*,  Pythagoras, Empedocles and Plato: the last one is said to "πυθαγοριζει" ("in genere Plato Pythagoram aemulatur"). 2/2

Answer (score 14):

The verb is πυθαγορίζω (infinitive πυθαγορίζειν), formed by adding the derivative suffix -ιζω to the name of Pythagoras (Πυθαγόρας).  So it just means "to be [or, in the context you quote, presumably, to act as] a disciple of Pythagoras"; or, to use an English equivalent, "to Pythagorize".

Sources:

- [The "Pythagorize" entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pythagorize) from Oxford Dictionaries (I'm not sure whether this coincides with *the* OED), which gives the etymology as "from ancient Greek Πυθαγορίζειν to be a disciple of Pythagoras from Πυθαγόρας, the name of Pythagoras + -ίζειν".
- [Perseus Greek word study tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=puqagori%2Fzw&la=greek#lexicon) [click on "LSJ"] translates it as "to be a disciple of Pythagoras", quoting uses: Antiph.226.8, Alex.220.1.
- The [entry for the suffix -ίζω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CE%AF%CE%B6%CF%89) in Wiktionary.

Comment: “Oxford Dictionaries” isn’t the same as the OED, but they’re sibling publications, from the same publishers.  The difference is explained [here](http://public.oed.com/about/the-oed-and-oxford-dictionaries/): broadly, the OED is more scholarly/historical, while Oxford Dictionaries focuses on accessibility and current usage.  The [OED entry for *Pythagorize*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155574) (paywalled, but usually accessible from universities) gives the same primary meaning as the Oxford Dictionaries entry, but adds a couple of mode recondite senses.